# How to connect 2 wallets locally to each other?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I remember somewhere I saw how to do it, but I can’t find
I want to run 2 wallets without nodes and connect them locally to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin Core supports `addnode` in the configuration which will add a dedicated outgoing peer to the defined IP address. `connect` will make a single outgoing connection to only that peer and nobody else.

Comment: But how to run 2 wallets at the same time?

Comment: You can start Bitcoin Core twice. You will need to start with `-listen=0` on one of them and use a different datadir.